# System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid table flickering moving to windows10

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

we bump to an issue I guess more Infrastructure related but will be requesting some programming solution.
the webpage is javascript on the aspx and vb.net as back end, not all computers but most of them are starting to flicker on the Datagrid table after moving to windows 10, using internet explorer.

some direction will be helpful thanks,
Y

Comment: I wouldn't think this would have anything to do with Windows 10. I would suspect browser version.

Comment: Hi Mary,
this might make the difference,
as different browsers of IE have reacting different to the mouse scroll.
I found out that version of 2013 is likely to to create the bug, running fast with the scroll up and down to a big amount of data make the table stacked and flickers.
i tried to debug it with the F12 tool and traced always on the anonymous class
    function anonymous()
    {
    return (datagrid.GetHeaderRowTop())
    }
 
but no crass in the code appears.
other IE of 2015 and 2018 this bug is not appearing
Y

Comment: Just to make the focus on , the issue is when using the mouse wheel, when moving fast up/down , the mouse is loosing connection with the data-grid and the table starts to flicker and no possibility to move up and down the table rows

Answer (score 0):

my work around was besicly to add -

```
overflow-y: scroll
```

and issue was resolved